# Sill plate patch shifted when it went into the anchors, how would you fix this?

Tags: repair, carpentry, renovation, building, sill

Title says it all, how would you handle a situation wherein you're patching a rotted sill plate and getting it perfect seems impossible?

The plate section is 13' long and has three threaded rods through it, dry fit was perfect, a hammer would have snug both ends together, but after if went down onto the studs the sill shifted, idk if the rods weren't 100% straight or my drill bit walked.

https://imgur.com/nNbVVpr
https://imgur.com/3ElJ9NS

Comment: If you are referring to the little gap at the end where new meets old, caulk it if you are concerned about leakage or drafts. If there is nothing bearing down on that particular spot, the gap itself is inconsequential. One end looks like a 1/4" gap the other maybe 1/2"-3/4"?

Comment: It’s not a big deal to embiggen the holes a little. If it looks terrible, just upsize the washer.

Comment: @Jack okay thank you, I'm new to this and have a very black and white / it's right or wrong mindset, the new sill section is just long enough to pressure fit, so the overlap on the right is ~3/16 and the gap on the left is 1/8"-1/4" (the old sill is cut tapered on the left because it was wobbly while I was sawing with my hackzall, I had planned for the ends of the 2x6 to be sandwiched in and the taper on the left would just leave a 1/8th" 'crack' midway through the 2x6 sill to be filled, but it shifted. I'm planning to lift the 2x6 and try to rubber mallet the rod ends a hair to the left

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Thank you, I'm glad to know I have the option to go to a 9/16" - 5/8" spade bit with a square washer

Comment: When building or repairing a house, everyone has the idea that it will be perfect.  The reality is that some measurements/fitting will be a tiny bit off.  It is when they are off a lot that you redo it/fix it.

Comment: If you want to tweak the rod a bit (don’t overdo it!) a section of metal pipe works better than a mallet.

Comment: You pour cement under there or you cut off a 1/4" so that when you pressure fit studs it pushes it down into contact with the concrete. As it is, it's going to make a 1/4" of contact, that will loosen eventually and then be able to drop. If it's a supporting wall, that's no good, and not ideal anyway otherwise. Then you put a shim (furring) to make up the difference and then sister the sill back together (if a stud goes there, sister the sill first)